# VBA find last row from a certain word and duplicate it

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help...

I really new in Macros. I want to find the last row of each Alphabet and then duplicate the whole row. I hope this is possible. If you see in the picture, the last row of A is row Nr. 8. so I want to duplicate this row, and insert it on row Nr.9. The last row of B is Nr. 15, so I want to duplicate it and insert into row nr. 16, and so on....

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need some code example for that task. thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. It is a Q&A website. If you are having trouble starting your project, there are plenty of tutorial websites out there. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office), [2](https://www.automateexcel.com/learn-vba-tutorial/), [3](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html). If you are stuck on a specific problem, then Stack Overflow is the perfect place to search for answers or ask a question if you can't find an answer that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with many ways. One of the ways is `FOR LOOP`.

**Code:**

```
Sub Add_dup()  
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range of cells", , , , , , , 8)

startrow = Rng.Row
startcol = Rng.Column
counter = 0

For i = startrow + 1 To Rng.Rows.Count + startrow + counter + Rng.Rows.Count + startrow
    For j = startcol To Rng.Columns.Count + startcol - 1
       If Cells(i, j) <> Cells(i - 1, j) Then
            Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Insert
            Range(Cells(i - 1, j - 3), Cells(i - 1, j)).Copy Range(Cells(i, j - 3), Cells(i, j))
            
            'Uncomment the below line to get the newly added rows highlighted
            'Range(Cells(i, j - 3), Cells(i, j)).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            i = i + 1
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

lastrow = Rng.Rows.Count + startrow
Range(Cells(lastrow - 1, startcol - 3), Cells(lastrow - 1, startcol)).Copy Range(Cells(lastrow, startcol - 3), Cells(lastrow, startcol))

End Sub
```

**Usage:**

- Since we are asking the range from user, macro will initially prompt you the range
- Select the range from start till end of the column (in your case, you need to select `D3` to `D31`)
- Note: This macro will work if you select 1 column only (in your case only `Kommentar_1`)

Answer (score 0):

Below are my codes. It's work but I am sure there is an easy way to do that. Next question: I have about 80 entries / category, in this sample code only 6 category (F1-F6). So if I have to copy and paste the code up to F80, it's really going to be a long code, isn't it? Is there a way to simplify it?

**Code:**

```
Sub Addrows()
Dim Fnd1 As Range, Finish
Count = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many row?", Default:=2)

F1:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("A", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
F2:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("B", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
F3:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("C", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
F4:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("D", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
F5:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("E", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
F6:
Set Fnd1 = Range("O:O").Find("F", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, , 
False)
Fnd1.EntireRow.Select
Fnd1.EntireRow.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox (Count & " was added")

End Sub
```